# Voltage mode and peak current mode

Tags: control

The voltage mode have several advantages, and I am confused 1.) and 2.)
1.)A large-amplitude ramp waveform provides good noise margin for a stable modulation process.
2.)A low-impedance power output provides better cross-regulation for multiple output supplies.

The peak current mode have some disadvantage, and I am confused 3.)
3.)With the control loop forcing a current drive,load regulation is worse and coupled inductors are required to get acceptable cross-regulation with multiple outputs.

I don't know what is this, can someone tell me in detail

Comment: Is this homework? What kind of modulator are you designing?

Comment: @Reinderien no this is not homework, I just want to know what difference between voltage mode and peak current mode control

Comment: Controlling what? This is vastly too vague.

Comment: @Jerry - Welcome :-) The 3 points you included in your question are copied from different parts of this Unitrode (now TI) document: "[Switching Power Supply Topology, Voltage Mode vs. Current Mode - Unitrode Design Note DN-62](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua119/slua119.pdf)". When asking questions on this site, it's important to explain the context, so readers can aim their answers at what you *don't* know & you should explain what you *do* already know. You said that you just want to know the difference between those two topologies - but the document explains that! So your question is unclear

Comment: @SamGibson Sorry, I will improve it

Comment: @SamGibson I am reading this document, and I don't know the advantage of voltage mode.
3.A low-impedance power output provides better cross-regulation for multiple output supplies
what that mean

Answer (score 2):

Voltage-mode and current-mode control have both pros and cons that I've tried to list below:

**Voltage-mode control (VM):**

1. easy to implement: the duty ratio is directly controlled by comparing an artificial ramp of comfortable amplitude (1-2 V for instance) with an error voltage representative of the correction to apply. A latch ensures a robust operation for double-pulse suppression.
2. naturally-low *open-loop* output impedance: take a buck converter, its output impedance in dc is the inductor ohmic loss \$r_L\$ in parallel with the load resistance. An open-loop buck converter operated from a constant input voltage can deliver a stable voltage almost independent from the load current as long as continuous conduction (CCM) mode is ensured.
3. the control-to-output transfer function of a voltage-mode-controlled converter operated in CCM (for the three basic switching cells, buck, buck-boost and boost) is that of a second-order type with a right-half-plane zero (RHPZ) for the last two cells. The resonant frequency for the boost and buck-boost converters moves with the duty ratio and complicates compensation.
4. when operated in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM), the cell remains a second-order system but heavily damped: a pole dominates in low frequency while the second is positioned at higher frequencies.
5. considering points 3 and 4, a well-compensated VM system must seamlessly transition between the two modes as load current varies. It can complicate a bit the compensation strategy.
6. a voltage-mode converter operated in its simplest form is blind to the inductor current. Modern converters now include a cycle-by-cycle current limit for a safe operation.
7. the above point is bad for robustness but is good for very narrow continuous (read non-skip) duty ratio operation but also for values well beyond 50% (for a buck for instance) without the need to resort to some sort of compensation.
8. a voltage-mode converter offers a poor input-voltage rejection. The input-to-output transfer function of a buck involves \$V_{in}\$ and it requires a high open-loop gain to reject the input variations.
9. finally, an opel-loop VM converter offers a positive incremental input resistance.

**Current-mode control (CM):**

1. the duty ratio generation now requires to observe the inductor current and you need a sensor for this. Usually, a resistance does the job or a current-sense transformer for high-power operations.
2. high *open-loop* output impedance. As the peak inductor current transforms the inductor in a constant current generator (as a first-order approximation), the dc output resistance is that of the load. Unlike the VM case, you cannot fix the peak current of a CCM-operated open-loop buck powered from a constant input and vary the load current. The output voltage will change significantly. You need a control loop to ensure proper operations.
3. the control-to-output transfer function of a current-mode-controlled converter operated in CCM (for the three basic switching cells, buck, buck-boost and boost) is that of a third-order type with the right-half-plane zero (RHPZ) as in VM. A pole dominates at low frequency and two poles are located at \$\frac{F_{sw}}{2}\$.The resonant frequency for the boost and buck-boost converters no longer moves with the duty ratio and eases compensation.
4. a current-mode converter is susceptible to sub-harmonic oscillations when operated in CCM and having a duty ratio approaching or exceeding 50%. These oscillations find their origin in the inner current-loop whose crossover is too high. Reducing crossover by the means of an external ramp is a way to cure these sub-harmonic oscillations. It complicates the analysis but nothing insurmountable.
5. when operated in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM), the cell changes to a damped second-order system where a pole dominates in low frequency.
6. considering points 3 and 5, a well-compensated CM system naturally seamlessly transitions between the two modes as load current varies. Compensation is easy.
7. It is difficult to generate very narrow pulses with a current-mode controller. What is called a leading-edge blanking (LEB) circuit is used to cleanse the inductor current which, practically speaking, blinds the control for several hundreds of nano-seconds. Added to the propagation delay, it limits the minimum pulse duration.
8. current-mode control naturally offers an excellent input voltage rejection (if the prop. delay is short) as the target is the inductor peak current: the switch remains on until the current setpoint is met whether this happens at lo- or hi-line. With a properly-compensated buck converter, you can even theoretically null the input voltage ac contribution.
9. finally, an open-loop CM converter offers a *negative* incremental input resistance.

Based on these remarks, CM seems certainly simpler to use compared to VM and most of today PWM controllers operate in current mode. Still, many dc-dc modules for the telecom industry are implementing voltage-mode control for the naturally-low output impedance and the absence of compensation ramp. This is all I can think of for tonight!

Comment: Sir,
what the 2 of voltage mode  mean the output impedance is low

Comment: what advantage of high open-loop output impedance
and what advantage of low open-loop impedance 
These two I don't understand

Comment: It means that the output resistance of the buck converter operated in CCM and VM is \$r_L||R_{load}\$. As \$r_L\$ is usually small (you want to minimized the ohmic inductor losses), the dc resistance is naturally small.

Comment: If you have a naturally-low output resistance, no need for a large open-loop gain compensator to reduce this resistance while you need one for a naturally-high output resistance as in CM for instance. I listed these points more as an observation. Most people don't care about this detail : )

Comment: Sorry,sir I am a student and not smart and I still have some question I would like to ask you.
1.) based on the above you list, the buck output impedance is not (Cout+esr)||RLoad||(L+ESL), why you just say rL||Rload
2.)So the low output impedance is good for control the Voltage right? the high output impedance is not good for control the voltage, but high output can make the system become 1order system

Comment: I see, an impedance is a term that implies a complex expression. A resistance is invariable with frequency. The open-loop output impedance of a buck is \$Z_{out,OL}(s)=R_0\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}\$ in which \$R_0\$ represents a resistance measured in dc conditions. If you consider the dc part only of the open-loop buck converter operated in voltage-mode control, you have \$R_0=r_L||R_{load}\$. If you close the loop, the impedance becomes \$Z_{out,CL}=\frac{Z_{out,OL}}{1+T(s)}\$ where \$T\$ is the loop gain.

Comment: So the low output impedance is good for control the Voltage right? And the high output impedance is not good for control the voltage, but high output can make the system become 1order system like peak current mode